# Use Non breakable space as thousands separator in pandas read_csv function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a iso-8859-1 formatted csv file to import to a pandas dataframe.

The read_csv function is great for that.

However the csv uses non breakable space as thousands separator and I don't seem able to remove it.

There is a thousands attribute in the read_csv function but whatever I put in there the unbreakable spaces are still there.

I tried the followings, all with the same result :

```
data_sheet = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="iso-8859-1", thousands=' ')
data_sheet = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="iso-8859-1", thousands=chr(160'))
data_sheet = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="iso-8859-1", thousands=u'\xa0')
data_sheet = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="iso-8859-1", thousands='\xa0')
data_sheet = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="iso-8859-1", thousands=unicodedata.lookup('NO-BREAK SPACE'))
```

Since it can not parse it pandas consider it as a string and return the following error when I try to convert it

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1\xa0279,92'
```

Comment: Could you show the original line of data containing `'1\xa0279,92'`? Is the comma in `'1\xa0279,92'` the decimal point or a comma separator for the CSV file?

Comment: The decimal is a ',' and the field separator is a ';'. I removed these parameters from my post for clarity. The full commande is the following. data_sheet = pd.read_csv(temp_file, header=25, encoding="iso-8859-1", sep=';', decimal=',', thousands=' ')

Comment: Here is an exemple of a full line. There are 175 columns so it is too long but here is a portion of it with the problematic fields :  0,11;1 279,92;1 324,21;1 302,14;10,65;2 707,77;2 951,71;2 829,40

Comment: OK. You may edit your post to include the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_csv` supports two parser engines: C and Python. According to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv),

```
The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete.
```

I did some tests and it looked like the C engine -- which is the default choice in most cases -- can only deal with thousands and decimal separators that are basic ASCII letters (`'\x0'` - `'\x7f'`); using `'\xa0'` as the thousands separator is only supported in the Python engine.

```
data = "0,11;1\xa0279,92;1\xa0324,21;1\xa0302,14;10,65;2\xa0707,77;2\xa0951,71;2\xa0829,40"
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), header=None, encoding="iso-8859-1",
                 sep=';', decimal=',', thousands='\xa0', engine="python")
df.info()
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   0       1 non-null      float64
 1   1       1 non-null      float64
 2   2       1 non-null      float64
 3   3       1 non-null      float64
 4   4       1 non-null      float64
 5   5       1 non-null      float64
 6   6       1 non-null      float64
 7   7       1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(8)
memory usage: 192.0 bytes
```

Comment: when adding engine='python', it works like a charm :-) Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

I too could not get `thousands=...` to work even with `decimal=','` and `dtype=...` thrown in.

What did work for me was supplying a `converter`.

Hopefully, others with more experience with pandas can show us how to use thousands correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import io


def to_float(s):
    return float(s.replace('\xa0', '').replace(',', '.'))


data = '''\
a,b,c
foo,bar,"1\xa0279,92"
foo,bar,"2\xa0280,93"
foo,bar,"3\xa0281,94"
foo,bar,"4\xa0282,95"
'''

f = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(f, converters={'c': to_float})

print(df)
```

Comment: What I ended up doing is first open the file as a txtfile with the standard python open() command, then remove all the unbreakable space, then save it as a new file and finally import it with pandas. It works but your way is much more elegant. Thanks :-)